# Adding two decimal point .00 when returning the result from web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a asp.net core web API project in that when I am returning a JSON result to the UI all the decimal values is converting to whole number, when I debug the controller I can see that two decimal point .00 but when I check it in the console network tab it is coming as whole number.

So, how can I add a formatter that will keep the decimal value as it is that is coming from the DB, it should not convert it to a whole number by the time it reaches the UI.

**When I debug the controller -**
[image]

**In the console network tab-**

[image]

Comment: Some place in the code you have variable declared as an int instead of a decimal.

Comment: Or `float`/`double` instead of `decimal` (any numeric type but `decimal` will have behavior you describe during JSON serialization)

Comment: Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could custom serializer for the decimal property

```
public class TestModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DecimalConverter))]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class DecimalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(decimal));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((decimal)value).ToString("0.00"));
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]